# Power BI embed on SharePoint is not showing UK date format for slicer visual

Tags: powerbi, date-format

We have slicer visual on our Power BI report. We need the slicer date display in dd/mm/yyyy format. The slicer is showing correct format before but recently we found that our report's slicer visual is showing mm/dd/yyyy format.

After further tests, we found BI report is NOT showing correct format only when embed on SharePoint page. It is showing correct format (dd/mm/yyyy) when browse in Power BI service or  Power BI desktop. We have tested with Edge and Chrome and both have same result.

We have checked our browser language setting, Windows local settings, Power BI file Option, SharePoint regional setting. All are set to English (U.K.). In fact, beside the slicer every other control are showing correct U.K. format on the same SharePoint site.

The issue can be easily reproduced by create a new Power BI report and embed on any SharePoint page.